# How to detect the existence of an element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var newHead = '<div id="head'+text+'"></div>';
var header = "head"+text;
if (document.getElementById(header) == undefined) {
        //alert(document.getElementById("head"+text));
        $("#result-job").append(newHead);
        var result = '<div id="div' + dataSplit[0] + '"><input type="radio" checked="checked" class="choosenJob" name="rdb_job" value="' + dataSplit[0] + '" id="' + dataSplit[0] + '" /><label for="' + dataSplit[0] + '">' + dataSplit[1] + '</label><br /></div>';
        $("div#" + header).append(result);
    } else {
        var result = '<div id="div' + dataSplit[0] + '"><input type="radio" checked="checked" class="choosenJob" name="rdb_job" value="' + dataSplit[0] + '" id="' + dataSplit[0] + '" /><label for="' + dataSplit[0] + '">' + dataSplit[1] + '</label><br /></div>';
        $("div#" + header).append(result);
    }
```

Can those script run well ?
I want add some new element(div) in the result div
but my script didnt work

fiddle simulation: http://jsfiddle.net/86kH4/5/

Comment: What does this have to do with Php?

Comment: do not use document.getElementById and $('#...') in the same block of code, it gets confusing

Comment: you can also use .length() > 0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an "exists" function for jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Comment: FWIW, your fiddle does not work because you have a syntax error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < `. Once you fixed that, your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/86kH4/28/

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
if (document.getElementById(header) == undefined) {
```

with

```
if ($("#" + header).length == 0) {
```

Comment: `header` is a variable in the OPs code, your jQuery code is not equivalent.

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks for pointing that out. Given the header variable contains the element id, simply concatonating the `#` with the variable should be fine. I updated the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You must add some quotes around your id, and it'll works fine. Also, remove the `== undefined`, let just Javascript check it :

```
if (document.getElementById("header")) {
   /* treatment */
} else {
   /* treatment */
}
```

Comment: Ok, then you know what changes to do ;) Avoid using the jQuery selector as mentionned in the other answer, the result will be an empty array. The basic javascript way is really more safe.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Q98mv/ - Please compare your snippet with this one and you will find where problem was

```
$('#chk1').click(function(){
    var ada = "asd";  //ada here will be my dynamic parameters                 
    var neww= '<div id="baru'+ada+'"></div>';

    if($('#baru'+ada).length==0){
        $("#asd").append(neww);
    }else{
        $("#baru"+ada).append("Hellow<br>");
    }
})​;
```

Comment: Please include code snippets in the body of the answer as well as via link to JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

here you should use a jquery function "live" 
for example:

```
$("div#" + header).live().append(result);
```

this function is used when the element was added appending the created elements~~
hope it is useful~~~

Comment: `.live` is for binding event handlers (and it's deprecated), but you don't bind any... it's useless calling it here.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, your fiddle has a syntax error, that's why it "does not work". Once you fixed the error, you get the expected behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/86kH4/28/.

---

**Yes**, you can use

```
document.getElementById(header) == undefined
```

to test whether an element with the ID contain in `header` exists or not.

If no such element exists, `getElementById` will return `null` and `null == undefined` is `true`. With that in mind, it would be even more correct if you were comparing against `null`:

```
document.getElementById(header) === null
```

---

That said, since you are using jQuery, I would try to be consistent and not mixing it with plain DOM methods. Every jQuery object has a `length` property containing the number of selected elements. So the jQuery equivalent would be:

```
$('#' + header).length === 0
```

Answer (score -1):

replace this `if (document.getElementById(header) == undefined) {` with `if ($('#header') == undefined) {` it may work fine. by the way you missed quotes for header in your code.

Comment: it wont be undefined - it will return an empty array

Comment: @JibiAbraham it wont return empty array, it returns null in both chrome and firefox :P

Comment: @shreedhar No it won't. Just tried it in Chrome and it returns an empty array. Just use `if($('#header').length)` http://jsfiddle.net/mMYcz/1/

Comment: jQuery **always** returns a jQuery object, even if no elements have been selected.